# Converting JSON to Dictionary in Swift using Alamofire

Tags: swift, alamofire

I would like to convert JSON data to Dictionary in Swift using Alamofire.
I was trying `if let dict = response.result.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> { ... }`, unfortunately it doesn't work. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance. This is example of printing my `response.result.value`

```
Optional(<__NSArrayI 0x6000002893d0>(
{
    category = category1;
    description = description1;
    name = sth1;
    id = 1;
    price = "213";
    type = type1;
},
{
    category = category2;
    description = description2;
    name = sth2;
    id = 2;
    price = "2133";
    type = type4;
},
{
    category = category3;
    description = description3;
    name = sth3;
    id = 3;
    price = "21334";
    type = type5;
}
)
)
```

Comment: why not use [ObjectMapper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwipqdDNzqPRAhWPN1AKHeXAA7wQFggbMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FHearst-DD%2FObjectMapper&usg=AFQjCNFyUn25wAdc4YI3J79e10bh5EsWTQ) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to extract the data from your Json step by step...
you can do it like this.

```
if let arrayOfDic = response.result.value as? [Dictionary<String,AnyObject>]{
        for aDic in arrayOfDic{
            print(aDic)//print each of the dictionaries
            if let price = aDic["price"] as? String{
                print(price)//print price of each dic
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Because your response is an array so you need to create an array of the dictionary. Only dictionary will not work from your above response.
So, change the code like below.

```
if let dict = response.result.value as? [[String : AnyObject]] 
{ ... }
```